# jquery bind on multiple anchor

Tags: jquery

I would like to bind the same event to a list of anchor link. Why this does not work?

Markup:

```
<a tabindex="0" href="#contactRoles" 
    class="fg-button fg-button-icon-right ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" 
    id="contactAdd">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>Aggiungi contatto</a>

<div id="contactRoles" class="hidden">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#1" class="contactRole">Cliente</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2" class="contactRole">Controparte</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3" class="contactRole">Avvocato</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4" class="contactRole">Avv. Controparte</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5" class="contactRole">Altre parti</a></li>
    <li><a href="#6" class="contactRole">Domiciliatario</a></li>
    <li><a href="#7" class="contactRole">Pubblico Ministero</a></li>
    <li><a href="#8" class="contactRole">Giudice</a></li>
    <li><a href="#9" class="contactRole">Istruttori</a></li>
    <li><a href="#10" class="contactRole">Studio Legale</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#contactAdd').menu({
    content: $('#contactRoles').html(),
    width: 150,
    showSpeed: 300
});

$("a.contactRole").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Link " + $(this).attr("href") + " clicked");
});
```

Where am I wrong?

**EDIT**:
@everybody: Yes the script is wrapped by a $(document).ready(...)

For further information consider that the div with class "hidden" is hidden and can only be viewed by a click on another anchor as you can see from this screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Lorenzo - Should still work. Are the `a.contactRole` elements added to the page dynamically (sometime *after* the page loads)?

Comment: No Patrick. They are only showed when clicked but that's static markup on the page...

Comment: Lorenzo - Try the edit I did at the top of my answer. Your code should work, but who knows. Also, does other jQuery code work on the page?

Comment: @Patrick: I have done another edit to the question to add the complete markup and jQuery code for the Button that shows the menu. Now I try with your suggestion...

Comment: It does not work even with the "live" approach! :(

Comment: Lorenzo - What is `.menu()`? If you get rid of that, do the click events work?

Comment: @Patrick: That is the plugin fg.menu from Filament Group that shows the dropdown using the unordered list. I think that this plugin is going to change the UL and I loose the binding in some way... What I am not understanding is why even the live feature fails...

Comment: @Patrick: The plugin create the dropdown at the first click on the button. please give a look here for more infos.... http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/

Comment: Lorenzo - The `live()` will fail if the `a.contactRole` elements (or any of their ancestors) has a click handler with `return false;` or `event.stopPropagation()`. I don't know how that plugin works, but I do have a feeling that it is overwriting the click events, and adding its own handlers that does one of the two things that will kill `.live()`. Looking at their docs, I was hoping they had a click event you could use. I don't see one. Is there any chance that you're calling `.menu()` *after* you added your `click` events?

Comment: Yes I have done that try. But it does not work either. I have seen, using developer tools of chrome that the UL il moved from the markup as a last child of the BODY element. I have also read that this plugin has been donated to the jQuery UI project that is working on it and it will be the official jQuery UI Menu plugin....

Comment: Lorenzo - Sorry, but I'm not sure what to tell you. If the plugin breaks your click events, there's not much you can do if you want to use that plugin. :o(

Comment: Lorenzo, there is an answer to this.  If nothing else, the fact that the plugin is interfering with your events is an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, you're already wrapped with a `ready()` function.

Another possibility is that the `a.contactRole` elements are added to the DOM *after* the page loads.

If that's the case, try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.contactRole").live('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Link " + $(this).attr("href") + " clicked");
    });
});
```

---

**Original answer:**

Should work. Have you made sure the document is loaded before assigning the click handler?

If the `<a>` elements haven't loaded when you try to assign the handler, it won't work.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kjSG8/

```
   // Wrap your code with $(function() {...}) to make sure it doesn't
   //    run until the DOM is fully loaded
$(function() {
    $("a.contactRole").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Link " + $(this).attr("href") + " clicked");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a standard event, are you declaring it within a `$(document).ready(function() {  });` block?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you create the click when the DOM is ready. You could also just say `$(".contactRole").click` instead of `$("a.contactRole").click`

Comment: To your second statement...I could be wrong, but I believe the jQuery selection is much faster when you define the element ahead of the classes.

Comment: @JasCav - I would agree with you there, but I find when people are new to jquery selectors, it's best to simplify the problems until a firm grasp is understood. (+1 Anyway) ^_^