# How to select an anchor element inside a div created at runtime with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this markup:

```
<body>
    ...
    ...
    <div class="helper">
        <div class="menu-container">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#" class="theLink">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="theLink">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="theLink">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I would like to select all the elements "a" with class "theLink".

Please note that the "helper" div as well as the "menu-container" div **are created at runtime**, after clicking on an anchor, by another jQuery plugin so I think I need to use the 'live' feature of jquery.

Thanks for helping

**EDIT**:
@everybody answered
Please, have a look a this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681373/jquery-bind-on-multiple-anchor).

Basically I am trying to attach a click event to the anchor that have "contactRole" class in that post. That anchors are modified by a plugin. If you want to have a good understanding of what is really needed please read all the comments.

Note that I have simplified the markup here: what is class="theLink" here is class="contactRole" in yesterday post.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you selecting them for?

Comment: I would like to attach a click event on it.

Comment: Lorenzo - The issue was not with binding the event. The issue was with the plugin's method of displaying the content. As far as I can tell, the elements are positioned `9999px` off the screen. The plugin uses the `.html()` value of the elements to display a copy of them when needed. If you go back to where you are binding the events, and add `.eq(2).click()` to the end, you'll see that the click event for the third item will fire. You just can't click on it because it is off the screen. I think it's a silly way to implement a menu, and would find a different plugin.

Comment: @patrick: ok! Thank you very much for the time spent in helping on this issue. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to select them, all the posted solutions will work perfectly, but if you actually want to do stuff when they're being clicked, try this:

```
$("a.theLink").live("click", function(event){
    //do stuff
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behaviour
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

I speed-read the plugin source code and I saw that a bunch of `.click()` handlers do a `return false` (lines 28, 211, 304, etc). I am fairly new to the use of the `.live()` function, but from what I understand, and as somebody actually pointed already in a comment to your other question, `.live()` will NOT work on an element that already has a `.click()` handler which returns `false`. In the case of this particular plugin, **I THINK** that `return false;`is used for preventing repetitive behaviour, like re-opening the menu if is already open, but I could be way off.

Giving you a definitive answer to your problem is hard, mostly because it would require me to know that plug-in really good, which I obviously do not. However, for starters I would modify that plugin by commenting out/removing all the `return false;` lines from `.click()` handlers and see what gets fixed and what gets broken.

Please let me know if/how this works out.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time spent in helping on this issue. If you have a look on patrick comment at my question, you'll see that he had deeper look at the plugin and the issue would not be solved in any case. Anyway, lot of thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `.live()`, that is for attaching events automatically to newly created elements.

```
$(a.theLink);
```

Will get you all of the elements of type `a`, with the class `theLink`.

Comment: This isn't an accurate description of `.live()` it doesn't attach handlers to new elements, it's a passive event listener.  Also, your selector needs quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("a.theLink");
```

And if you are binding a event to these links, yes you must use live if page get new content after initial reload.

So, you can use:

```
$("a.theLink").live("click", function(){
    alert("clicked!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter when they're created, and "live" is something completely different -- it's a tool for event handling / event delegation, not selectors.

`$('a.theLink')` or `$('ul.menu a.theLink')` or whatever (depending on whether you want to look globally) will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will select from whatever is on the page at the time it runs.  So it depends on how/where the jQuery function will be called.

For example, if you wanted to reference these links after they have been created, you would just use `$('a.theLink')` or `$('ul.menu a.theLink')` or etc.

If you wanted to set events to these elements before they are even created, then you would use live.  Maybe something like below which would link up to the current `a.theLink`'s and any `a.theLink`'s that will be created in the future.

```
$('a.theLink').live('click', function() {
  // Live handler called.
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/